# transfering kernel image to another system

Tags: server, kernel

my server system is low on disk. To install a new kernel I think i shall do the following:

1. compile the kernel on another system.
2. copy bzImage along with config, System.map and of course the laodable module in /lib/modules and transfer them to the server.
3. Now, I can remove the server's old kernel to free up the space and put the the files in /boot as well as copying loadable modules to

no,... this is not the way, this way I need to make the drivers the image as well. There's another way, in ubuntu I can make .deb files of the headers and the linux, if I transfer only those two files to the server, I think i can install the new kernel using dpkg. what do you think?

Comment: What's wrong with the default server kernel?

Answer (score 1):

If you have another Ubuntu system with the same processor architecture (or with properly set up cross-compiler environment), you can build kernel packages on that system, copy the resulting .deb files to your server and install. An overview of the procedure is available for example in community document [Kernel/Compile](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile).